# Zend Framework 1 force HTTPS

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

How can I force HTTPS using Zend Framework 1, `Zend_View_Helper_Url` and the request object?

I got this but am looking for a ZF1 way without concatting _SERVER variables...

```
if (!$this->getRequest()->isSecure()) {
    $this->redirect(
        'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    );
}
```

Please don't suggest `.htaccess` solutions. There are too many questions asking for Zend code answered with mod_rewrite suggestions.

I know you can pass `options` to the URL/redirect helper but I'm not sure how it's done.

Pseudocode:

```
$this->redirect(array('useHttps' => true), $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
```

Comment: Simple question : why don't you want to use `$_SERVER` variables ?

Comment: @php-dev I'm going to use those vars but I'd prefer a Zend solution. I'm pretty sure it exists, I just can't find it.

Comment: There isn't a `dedicated way` to do it but you should :
Set the Redirector to Use Absolute Uri
$this->_helper->redirector->setUseAbsoluteUri(true);
Hack the $_SERVER global array 
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
then $this->redirect($url); should take you over HTTPS

Comment: The only possible options are `exit`, `code` and `prependBase`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the serverUrl() helper

```
// Current server URL in the example is: http://www.example.com/foo.html

echo $this->serverUrl();
// Output: http://www.example.com

echo $this->serverUrl(true);
// Output: http://www.example.com/foo.html

echo $this->serverUrl('/foo/bar');
// Output: http://www.example.com/foo/bar

echo $this->serverUrl()->getHost();
// Output: www.example.com

echo $this->serverUrl()->getScheme();
// Output: http

$this->serverUrl()->setHost('www.foo.com');
$this->serverUrl()->setScheme('https');
echo $this->serverUrl();
// Output: https://www.foo.com
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html

Answer (score 2):

```
    protected function _initForceSSL() {
      if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '443') {
         header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
         exit();
       }
    }
```

Put this function into your bootstrap file